# Adding additional data source to Power BI SQL import :

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery

I need to add the second data source to the script below:

Source one: `"SysproCompanyG"` -- > Already exist and works

Source two: `"SysproCompany2"` -- > I want to add it to the query

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("mayon-repl", "SysproCompanyG" , [Query="select ParentPart from BomStructure#(lf)group by ParentPart#(lf)"]),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"ParentPart", "SCode"}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{{"SCode", Text.Trim, type text}})
in
    #"Trimmed Text"
```

Comment: Can you outline why you want to add a second data source, what outcome do you want? Can you not just set up another connection, then link it via a join or relationship, if connecting tables?

Comment: If it's another SQL query, then perhaps you should adjust your underlying SQL code. Alternatively, you can create a separate query in Power Query for SysproCompany2, and then Append it (or merge it) to the existing query?

Comment: @Jon Our company separated business entities this way for some reason, for example G represents Canada while 2 represents US , I wanted to add this two together .

Comment: @JustynaMK Yes can appends for sure but I was trying to avoid that if there is a way , I thought it might run faster this way

Comment: Thanks @JalalMirahmadi , I see Sql query is the source of your data for `SysproCompanyG`. Is `SysproCompany2` also stored in the same database? Cannot you adjust your Sql query to extract both companies at the same time?

Comment: @JustynaMK yes, same database . How would you adjust it to ?